# move uploaded image into folder in php(move_uploaded_file() function)

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, move

I have a problem with moving uploaded files.

```
<?php
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'] ;
$target_file = "../uploads/$image_name";
$targetFileForItem = "uploads/$image_name";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file);


$sql = "INSERT INTO items (name , description,`price`, `country`, `release`, `condition`, `image`) 
        VALUES ('$name','$description','$price', '$country', '$date', '$condition', '$targetFileForItem')" ;

?>
```

the variable `$targetFileForItem` works currect, and inserts into my db very well, but the file don't move into `$target_file`var's folder, which is `uploads`. As you see I use `move_uploaded_file()` function, but i's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the permission of the uploads folder

Comment: the whole code is correct

Comment: definitely a permissions issue, and/or a path issue.

Comment: I think it's a permission issue, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @ArevshatyanGegham are you using FTP or localhost ? if it's in FTP than right click on the folder and change it's permission to 755.

Comment: Then there must be path issues double check your path and folder name. If you want to check then use file_exists . see my edited answer below for file_exist code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your permission for upload folder it must be 775. If you are using FTP than right click on folder and change File permission of that folder to 755.
If it's localhost then it must be a path or folder name issue.

And make your code like this so you can get find out errors also.

```
<?php
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'] ;
$target_file = "../uploads/$image_name";
$targetFileForItem = "uploads/$image_name";

// if folder not exists than it will make folder.

if(!file_exists($target_file))
{
       mkdir($target_file, 0777, true);
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file))
{
      echo "file successfully uploaded";       
}
else
{
      echo "error in file upload";
}

?>
```

Comment: it started to move image, but it prints an error too: "Undefined variable: target_dir". can you explain me why we need `$target_dir`var?

Comment: my mistake $target_dir will be $target_file. just edited my answer.

Comment: as I changed the variable to `$target_file`, it comes up with another error, and didn't ulpoad the file.
error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory,

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move,

error in file upload

Answer (score 1):

Write this to `debug`

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If your code is ok then check `file permissions` you can use this

```
if (is_dir($target_file ) && is_writable($target_file )) {
    // do upload logic here
} else {
    echo 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.';
}
```

`is_writable` `Returns TRUE` if the filename exists and is `writable`. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable

for more info read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: ok, I tried, and noticed that `is_dir($target_file)` is not working. So what can I do for it?

Comment: If problem is in is_dir() that means no direcort exist. Check your file path then